# Material FIFA World Cup Football Goal Posts

Tags: football, equipment, trivia, world-cup

In my younger years, when I still played football, I got rid of the dirt underneath my football shoes by smashing them against one of the goal posts. I remember the sound to have a high pitch.

What kind of material are the goal posts made of, used at the FIFA World Cup 2014?

Comment: It might depend on the venue.  There are [12 different stadiums](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2014_FIFA_World_Cup_venues) being used for the 2014 FIFA World Cup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was unable to find a definitive answer about the specific materials used for the 2014 FIFA World Cup, but here are some of the regulations I could find.

According to the official "Regulations of the 2014 FIFA World Cup":

> ### 33 Stadiums, fields of play, clocks, displays
>
> 1. The Organising Association shall ensure that the stadiums and facilities in
>      which the matches of the final competition take place fulfil FIFA
>      requirements and comply with the FIFA Safety Regulations and other FIFA
>      guidelines and instructions for international matches.

According to the [Laws of the Game 2014/2015](http://www.fifa.com/mm/document/footballdevelopment/refereeing/02/36/01/11/27_06_2014_new--lawsofthegameweben_neutral.pdf) (PDF):

> The goalposts and crossbar must be made of wood, metal or other
>    approved material.

And lastly, here are some technical details about the goalposts used in the World Cup from [Football Stadiums: Technical recommendations and requirements - 5th Edition](http://www.fifa.com/mm/document/tournament/competition/01/37/17/76/stadiumbook2010_buch.pdf) (PDF): [image]

Answer (score -1):

The goals in the world cup were made out of Steel that was powder coated to protect from weather. They would still make the same noise if you were to bang a boot on them today.

Hope this helped.

Comment: Can you add a reference for that, in relation to the FIFA World Cup 2014?

Comment: I#m pretty shure it's not powder coated steel. In the german Bundesliga all goal are made out of aluminium. Just think of the weight a powder coated steel gaol would have.

Comment: I remember a text that said most permier league clubs use uPVC (unplasticized polyvinyl chlorid) goals in trainig. They would be much lighter than the aluminium goals.